# Oracle: SELECT where date is less if not equals null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of records, and one column holds the value when the records turns in-active.
Most of the records are still open, and therefore do not hold any value in the `end_date` column.

I want to select all of those records, which are still active. One way to achieve this (from the top of my head):

```
select *
from table t
where nvl(t.end_date, to_date('2099-DEC-31', 'MM-DD-yyyy')) > sysdate
```

But it doesn't feel right. Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

EDIT: BTW, the table isn't huge, and isn't going to grow :)

Comment: This is commonly used... Also, you can even create a function based index with the `nvl()` expression to make it speedier. (if, and only if you need that optimization)

Comment: It is not right, because is 'MM-DD-yyyy'. Should be 'yyyy-mon-dd'. :)

Comment: @Florin Ghita - *top of my head.

Comment: how about: select ... where end_date is null

Comment: I see a Year 2099 bug here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
  from table t
 where nvl(t.end_date, to_date('2099-DEC-31', 'MM-DD-yyyy')) > sysdate
```

won't use a "normal", non function based index, so it may hurt performance.

You could query it like

```
select *
  from table t
 where t.end_date > sysdate OR t.end_date is null
```

instead

Comment: But in the second case, it could still suffer from indexes not covering the NULL values, if the time goes by, and there will be more and more closed values there, making a full table scan costlier... (but reading this again, this might count as a premature optimization)

Comment: Thanks .. totaly forgot about the 'OR' possibility ..  :o)

Comment: You're absolutely right @ppeterka.. I think only few optimizations are premature. 
If this column is the only column used in the index, it would most likely result in a table scan. I was biased on own experience, as most of the times when filtering on dates I have other constraints too that are part of the index, so some null values won't affect index usage. Thanks on the hint to make it clear!